# How to access props and setState in React 15.6 with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

After updating a react app to typescript 15.6 everything breaks because it can no longer find props and setState on the React.Component.

I've been googling but can't find any typescript specific information for migrating to react 15.6.

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import { connect } from 'react-redux';

@connect(state => ({auth: state.auth}))
class App extends React.Component<{auth?: any}, any> {
      render() {
        if (this.props.auth.user == null) return <div><LoginModal /></div>;
        return <div>...stuff here...</div>
      }
}
```

[image]

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./components/pages/tags/tag-item.tsx:74:78 
    TS2339: Property 'props' does not exist on type 'TagItem'.

ERROR in [at-loader] ./components/pages/tags/tag-item.tsx:76:14 
    TS2339: Property 'setState' does not exist on type 'TagItem'.
```

Here are my dependencies for the project.

```
"dependencies": {
    "color": "^2.0.0",
    "geolib": "^2.0.22",
    "history": "^4.6.1",
    "immutability-helper": "^2.3.0",
    "react-google-maps": "^7.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.6",
    "react-router": "^4.1.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^2.2.1",
    "radium": "^0.19.4",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.13",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "firebaseui": "^2.2.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.0.0-beta.19",
    "babel-core": "^6.22.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.10",
    "react-container-query": "^0.8.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.1.6",
    "typescript": "^2.1.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.6.1"
  }
```

Comment: Have you installed something those too while shifting to typescript. 

 "@types/history": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^0.14.29",
    "@types/react-dom": "^0.14.14",
    "@types/react-redux": "^4.4.29",
    "@types/react-router": "^2.0.30",
    "@types/react-router-redux": "4.0.30",
    "@types/redux": "3.5.27",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.0",

Comment: added my deps. not sure what you are getting at. I've always been on typscript. I was shifting from 15.4 to 15.6. Thanks for looking

Comment: Can you install @types packages that required for typescript.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/react

And other mentioned above comment. install one by one react first

Comment: Just go to definition of React.Component (F12 in VS for example), and look how it declared (and what typings your IDE found). Looks like you are using invalid typings.

Comment: @FarzamBabar - there doesn't appear to be a react-dom 16.6.1 there is for react. Do you mean to install the versions you typed or ones that map to my current instalation? - edit: tried install latest of all of those and get more errors (redux notices missing props var too now)

Comment: version which you like, try latest one,

I told you try one by one., may be some not required to your project

Comment: well, i ended up having to install the types for react and react-dom and removing the "react": "^15.6.1" and just leaving it external. If you want to answer I'll accept your suggestion as correct.